# Should Civic Duty and Electorate be put between the same hr tags in the Badges list?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Perhaps they aren't directly related as the other bronze-silver-gold badge progressions, but it seems like they could be grouped with each other in the list.

Comment: Are you referring to the section where things are [grouped by function](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges) (these both fall under Moderation) and then listed alphabetically?

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay attention to the alphabetical sorting. So I guess the answer is that they aren't directly related.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about genreal stack exchange and should be migrated to meta.stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes they are related, and just a degree of how sustained your moderation efforts on the site relate to the voting buttons.

My hope is that everyone that decides to chase the Electorate badge is then so used to the positive effect of voting, that the site grows people that help moderate what content is featured.

The listing at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges seems to be organized alphabetically to my eye. ;-)

Comment: maybe they could be put between the same hr tags then?

Comment: @dwightk If you want to ask that, just edit the question and I'll delete this. Be sure to tag **bug** or **feature-request** and possibly site-design if you feel that last tag fits the bill.